# angular 5 - how to use Angular Material tooltip

Tags: angular, angular-material, tooltip

I'm following this link to implement a tool tip in angular 5.

https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/api

But I am not understanding how practically implement this.

any body can add an example of a ts and html files of how to implements it ?

**edit**

Thanks for all quick responses.

i try to add this to my html:

```
  <button mat-raised-button matTooltip="Info about the action" aria-label="Button that displays a tooltip">

  </button>
```

and this in the ts:

```
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material';
```

but now i getting this error in the console:

> Error: The "mat-" prefix cannot be used in ng-material v1 compatibility mode. It was used on an "button" element.
>   Error: The "mat-" prefix cannot be used in ng-material v1 compatibility mode. It was used on an "button" element

any bode know why? thanks!

Comment: You can check the usage link on top of each "examples"  eg: https://stackblitz.com/angular/olmqmkqopgr

Answer (score 0):

You need to import **`MatTooltipModule`** from `@angular/material`

```
import { MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material';
```

and wherever you want to use the tooltip, use **`matTooltip`**

```
<button mat-raised-button matTooltip="Tooltip Display" matTooltipShowDelay="1000"
matTooltipHideDelay="2000" aria-label="displays a tooltip">
  Tooltip Button
</button>
```

**[`STACKBLITZ DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tooltip-material-jtymsr)**

Answer (score 0):

Solution:-

```
<button mat-raised-button
        matTooltip="Info about the action"
        aria-label="Button that displays a tooltip when focused or hovered over">
  Action
</button>
```

import { MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material';

Link:-

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-xfs8ur?file=app/app.component.html

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cvtwy1?file=material-module.ts

Comment: @Levi, for error you are getting , refer- https://github.com/Teradata/covalent/issues/923

Comment: Which version fo angular/material , you are using. Try updating to latest one

Comment: With current version `import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';`